# GE Smallworld PNI 4.3 forgot Administrator Password

Tags: authentication, smallworld-gis

I forgot the Administrator password for my company's Smallworld PNI installation, we had been making due with just the user accounts but now the user accounts don't log in anymore, is there anyway to reset the Admin password

Comment: What database is the backend for Smallworld in your case? (most likely oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do know your way around the cli/magik, you can start an open image with a "-noinit" parameter, then open the database and fiddle around with the authorisation database.